# What BASH command can match a user who filled up considerable disk space (around 30%) in /opt?

Tags: linux, users, disk-usage

Sometimes we get into a problem where are unable to figure out what caused the disk to be filled. Therefore, if we have a BASH one liner/script which can catch the uid of the users and pid with time, then we can approach those users directly. Monitoring tools tell you the time of the I/O spike, but you do not know what caused it. Therefore such one-liner will be useful This applies to all the Linux based systems.

One way might be with detecting system calls. This question is for all Linux Systems. I don't know what I am missing here.

Comment: Have you considered enabling quotas?

Comment: Lets say if a process does it instead of user. Then what is the way to detect it?

Comment: A user is running the process, always.  There are never any anonymous processes.

Comment: Lets say if we cannot enable quotas because of some restriction . What is a way of detecting the user?

Comment: Or the quotas are enabled and we just have to detect the recent file that filled up the directory, then how can this be done?

Comment: When you say "spike" ... the disk gets filled and then "flushed" again soon after?  Otherwise it shouldn't be too hard to find the biggest file ...

Comment: Sorry. The space doesn't get flushed. The space stays.

Comment: If the files are actually created by different users (i.e. different file owners), and one of them is using 30% of disk space, then you could start by detecting who that user is, by using something like the solution suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/597173/333789), which relies on `find`.

Comment: The solution relies on already knowing who the user is and then finding his usage. So it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

This gives to the 20 biggest files under `/opt` with size and username

```
find /opt/ -type f -printf "%s\t%u\t%p\n" | sort -k1,1n | tail -n 20
```

Comment: (it assumes the GNU implementation of `find` and that file paths don't contain newline characters).

Answer (score 0):

If the ownership/group of the files in question does not provide the information you require (IE via [tink’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557146/40482)), you’re not going to be able to easily determine who did what after the fact.

Perhaps you can scrape system logs to piece together evidence based on who was logged on at the time, coupled with logs of elevating privileges — availability of such depends on your set up, specifically how users are switching to another account to create the data. This is not likely to be the “one liner” you are seeking.

Otherwise you’re looking at enabling `auditd` and using that to actively monitor the `/opt` directory/file system for changes. With this in place your “one liner” is the post-fact filter of the audit log.

See for example: [How to monitor file/directory changes](https://serverfault.com/questions/297443/how-to-monitor-file-directory-changes)

However, audit logs can be big so that adds on a new consideration for you.